# How to add WWW to domain in AWS Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have created a Record Set

```
Name: www.nevermind.com.
Type: A
Alias Target: nevermind.com.
```

`nevermind.com` is working but `www.nevermind.com` is not working.

I get an error: `404 Not Found`

**update:** I'm using s3 service to host my code.

Any ideas?

Comment: `404` is not a DNS error, check your web/application server.

Comment: @DusanBajic my website without www works great. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For s3 hosted websites - to enable the www subdomain for your domain, you need to do the following -

- Create another s3 bucket with your subdomain name - www.nevermind.com
- In the www.nevermind.com bucket choose properties -> static website hosting -> choose redirect requests -> in target bucket/domain put your domain "nevermind.com"
- save
- In route53 DNS record, create a new record set -> enter "www" for the Name -> select Alias: "Yes" -> use the "www.nevermind.com" s3 bucket alias endpoint.

After this, your www.nevermind.com should redirect to nevermind.com.

Comment: What if I want to have an url like `www.example.com` which nevertheless will redirect to `example.com` behind the scenes but still look like `www.example.com` like for instance this one `https://www.google.com/` ?

Answer (score 0):

First verify in DNS Settings correct IP address is provided for the www entry - 
In route53 zone records you must see an entry with Name as www and value as IP address of your server.

Second - 
In your webserver's virtualhost settings you need to add both www and root domains, like below.

If you are using apache -

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin xx@xxxx.com
    ServerName www.nevermind.com
    ServerAlias *.nevermind.com nevermind.com
    ....
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

If nginx -

```
server {
  listen 80;
  #listen 443 ssl default_server;
  server_name nevermind.com www.nevermind.com;
  ....
  ....
```

Comment: What do you mean - webserver's virtualhost settings?

Comment: oh ok, please update your question and mention about using s3 based website. I am adding another answer for s3 based website

Comment: i have added the answer :)